# how to assign a class to a div when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

i am trying to assign a class to a div when a checkbox is checked. currently the code i have is working but i have a few div's and when a single item is checked it assigns the class to all of the divs.

js code.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){       
if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(".widget").addClass("services services-active"); 
}else{
    $(".widget").removeClass("services-active");  
}

});
```

html

```
     <div class="services widget" id="div1">
        <div class="name">Support1</div>
        <div class="cat">Test1</div>
        <div><input id="1" type="checkbox" name="1"/></div>
        </div>

     <div class="services widget" id="div2">
        <div class="name">Support2</div>
        <div class="cat">Test1</div>
        <div><input id="2" type="checkbox" name="2"/></div>
        </div>
```

how can i assign the class separately to each parent div? do i need to do js code for each div and use div id or can i add a .each statement to the js code?

Comment: Just change this `$(".widget")` to this `$(this).parents(".widget")`.

Comment: i tried that method earlier but it did not append the class to the div

Comment: downvoter, please remove your downvote. i am fixing my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){       
    $(this).closest('.widget').addClass('services').toggleClass('services-active', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/rtfy5v3a/)

Note that the elements actually already have the class `services`, and that you're only adding it, not removing it ?
And you need to **actually close** those inputs in the HTML

Comment: thank you this works. actually the tags are closed, i modify some code here to protect user identity and i mistakenly forgot to close the tags

Comment: i am not removing it because the service class is just a padding. if i remove it the div looses it's padding and does not look well

Comment: But why do you keep adding it? If it's already there it's not added again, so it's not an issue at all, it just seemed a little strange.